# I have some problem with child class that how to use the super.method()

Tags: java, inheritance

my child class is

```
public class User extends Alien
{

public User(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister, int lifePoints, String name)

{

super(currentLocation, energyCanister,lifePoints, name);

}

    public int collectCanister(NormalPlanet canister)
    {
        super.collectCanister();
        return energyCanister;
    }

}
```

my parent class is:

```
public class Alien
{

protected XYCoordination currentLocation;

protected Planet currentPlanet;

 protected int energyCanister;

 protected int lifePoints;

protected int n;

 private String name;

    public Alien(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister)
    {
        this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
        this.energyCanister = energyCanister;
        this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
        this.name = name;
    }

...

    public int collectCanister(NormalPlanet canister)
    {
        energyCanister = energyCanister + (int)(n*canister.getRemainingCanister());
        return energyCanister;
    }
...

}
```

when I compile it, the child class with

```
public int collectCanister(NormalPlanet canister)
{
    super.collectCanister();
    return energyCanister;
}
```

is not working? What can i do?

Comment: "is not working" is an incredibly vague description. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then edit your question

Comment: what do you mean it is not working? What is happening? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `super.collectCanister(...)` takes an argument and second the constructor for `Alien` should take two more arguments - otherwise both `lifePoints` and `name` **will not be set**!

This is your "new" call to `super.collectCanister` method:

```
public int collectCanister(NormalPlanet canister)
{
    super.collectCanister(canister);
    return energyCanister;
}
```

And this is how your constructor for alien should look like:

```
public Alien(XYCoordination currentLocation, 
             int energyCanister, 
             int lifePoints, 
             String name) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public User(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister, int lifePoints, String name)  {
   super(currentLocation, energyCanister,lifePoints, name);
}
```

I can't see how this will work? The super does not contain four parameters, only currentLocation, and eneryCanister.

You need to change the signature of your Alien constructor to be

```
public Alien(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister, int lifePoints, String name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SuperKonstructor takes only two arguments:

```
public Alien(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister)
{
    this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    this.energyCanister = energyCanister;
    this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
    this.name = name;
}
```

and not four as you do it in your subclass. And additionally in your super constructor you assign name and lifePoints to fields of this class, but lifePoinbts and name aren't constructor arguments.